# How does the RarePackFour smartcontract generate a new "unique" number from a given random number?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to understand the RarePackFour smart contract from the game gods unchained. I noticed that they use a random number to generate other "random" (in parenthesis because i dont think the newly generated numbers are random).
This the code im trying to understand. Could you help me understand what is happening here  ?

```
function extract(uint random, uint length, uint start) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return (((1 << (length * 8)) - 1) & (random >> ((start * 8) - 1)));
    }
```

Bitwise operators are not realy a strong point for me so it would really help if you can help understand what is happening in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go with example:

```
length = 1
start = 1
random = 3250 # Binary: 0b110010110010

1. ((1 << (length * 8)) - 1) = 2^8 - 1 = 255 = 0B11111111 # Binary

2. (random >> ((start * 8) - 1))) = 0b110010110010 >> 7 = 0B11001 # Decimal 25


0B11111111 & 0B11001 = 0B11001 = 25
```

Usually if `length * 8` > `((start * 8) - 1)`, the function returns `random / (start * 8 - 1)`. Notice that it's only integer calculation in Solidity.

Comment: do you think that the approach the people using this code have taken is good for just getting a number out of the random number ? and would this generally result in a unique number each time ? also, do you have any resources for learning bitwise operations, like mathematical approaches tricks and stuff ? thanks @pySOL.

Comment: I personally don't think this is a good way to get a random number, because this number generated via a formula and people can guess it easily. I don't know any trick for the bitwise, but the bitwise operator works on binary, so we can convert the decimal to binary and enjoy it.

Comment: I looked into the Rare Pack Four SC, and saw that this is the random generator: `random = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(i, rand, j)));`. The `rand` here is again come from this function: `uint random = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bhash, p.user, address(this), p.count)));` Finally the function were discussing aimed to extract the value from the generated random uint.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Yeah I was aware about their approach to generating the random numbers, they are using a flow similar to chainlink's request receive cycle, however the difference is that they are doing it in a centralized way. I was just wondering if it was a valid approach for extracting a new number out of the random number using the bitwise operations in the extract method.